# PHP - Turn a string like "eg1 - eg2 - eg3" into an array using " - " as the value separator

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have a string like this: `"eg1 - eg2 - eg3"`.

I would like to turn that string into an array. So, the array would have 3 keys and I could then loop through those keys.

Could anyone provide some information relating to how I could accomplish this task using PHP?

Comment: To be fair, the name "explode" doesn't exactly jump out and scream "hey, use me to split a string!".  Though `split` kinda does, it's deprecated.

Comment: @cHao Well then you can understand me... I was thinking split too.

Comment: normally I don't like RTFM answers, but really... Don't they teach you how to google nowadays? just try "php string array separator" ;)

Comment: @cypherabe why must I google if I can ask a question on here and have a reference to it forever? Yes google does work but this question provided me with all the info google could have, and more! I don't really understand comments like that but thank you anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is always a whitespace between the "-"

```
$parts = explode(' - ', $string);
```

Better split with regex

```
$parts = preg_split("\s-\s" , $string);
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. Out of your two examples, which one do you think would be less resource intensive? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use the PHP [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function to break up the string into an array on the delimiter `' - '` like this - then you can loop through it.

```
$myArray=explode(' - ', $myString);
```

Answer (score 2):

explode, not preg_split.
Use preg_ only if you have to use reg exp. Explode is much faster. So

> If there is always a whitespace between the "-"

definitely use explode

Comment: "One thing to note is that preg_split() uses Perl Compatible Regular Expressions (PCRE).  For a POSIX Extended Regular Expression split use the split() function.  

In any case, explode() is the fastest of the three functions if you do not need regular expressions.  If you want to split by character count (rather than a patter) you may want to look into str_split()."